# Strange include error during Android NDK app development

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, oculus

I am struggling with some funny, but annoying error in my C++ Android native app. I am extending already working example from [Oculus Mobile SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-native-samples/) called VrCubeWorld_SurfaceView.

The problem is constant error: `defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]` when I want to add my own simple class that is only including `App.h` from SDK.

My class header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef VRAPP_H_
#define VRAPP_H_

#include "App.h"

using namespace OVR;

namespace AiLab {

class VrApp : public OVR::VrAppInterface
{
public:
                VrApp();
    virtual     ~VrApp();

    void        OneTimeInit();

    OvrGuiSys*  GuiSys;
};
}
#endif /* VRAPP_H_ */
```

This is my cpp file of a class:

```
#include "VrApp.h"

namespace AiLab {
VrApp::VrApp():
    GuiSys(OvrGuiSys::Create())
{

}

VrApp::~VrApp()
{
    OvrGuiSys::Destroy(GuiSys);
}

VrApp::OneTimeInit()
{
    GuiSys->Init( app, &app->GetSoundMgr(), app->LoadFontForLocale(), &app->GetDebugLines() );
}
}
```

What is more interesting is that functions that tend to display this error are in face used, so I comment it out then another error emerge.

Can anyone advice what might be wrong?

Comment: A guess: the compiler may believe that the function is never called, sort of `if(0){myfunc();}`. In this example you have to define _myfunc()_ to get it compiled, but _myfunc()_ will indeed never be called.

Answer (score 0):

As [marcinj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471160/marcinj) stated, you can just comment the unused function 'OneTimeInit' to fix this warning, because the compiler thinks this function is not necessary exist in your code since nobody use it at all.

```
class VrApp : public OVR::VrAppInterface
{
public:
                VrApp();
    virtual     ~VrApp();

    // void        OneTimeInit();

    OvrGuiSys*  GuiSys;
};
```

Comment: I've tried both and still nothing has changed. Beside I need this because from OvrGuiSys I can have GlazeCursor

Comment: Interesting, could you please show the code around the error? sometimes, error is caused by previous statements, compiler may confused by the code.And another approach is to add your code as simple as possible to narrow down the problem, such as just add ctor and dtor of your own class.